# /me/inbox doesn't return all messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

/me/inbox, and the threads in it, don't seem to contain all mesages. When paging all the way to the end, no messages from more than a couple of months ago are there. Any workarounds?

(The new /me/threads api seems to solve this, but the threads-api is still unavailable for non-developers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All messages *are* actually in the Graph, you just can't see them.**

You can see for yourself that all messages are still there, by selecting a thread-id, and appending "_messagenumber" to it. /threadid_000 will retrieve the first message in that thread, even when you can't retrieve that message by paging through the thread.

**Then how come I can't retrieve them normally?**

The problem seems to be in the paging links. Paging uses the "until" and "since" parameters to get the next batch of messages. General form of a thread paging-link:

> graph.facebook.com/**messageid**/comments?limit=25&since=**epoch**&__paging_token=**token**

What a 'next' paging link in the inbox does is, it moves **epoch** to a time further in the past. Unfortunately, the **until**(and **since**) parameter in inboxes [is broken](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/391740130882377/).

**So how do I solve this?**

Don't page using the paging links. Use **offset**. Retrieve the first page, then page by adding the number of messages you retrieved plus one to the **offset** parameter.
In pseudocode:

```
offset=0
do 
 {
    response=make_api_call('{$threadid}?offset={$offset}&limit=25')
    offset+=length(response)+1
    while length(response)>0

 }
```

Let's say a thread contains 100 messages. These API-calls would be made to retrieve all messages, from newest to oldest:

> graph.facebook.com/threadid/comments?offset=**0**&limit=25
>
> graph.facebook.com/threadid/comments?offset=**26**&limit=25
>
> graph.facebook.com/threadid/comments?offset=**51**&limit=25
>
> graph.facebook.com/threadid/comments?offset=**76**&limit=25

Do make sure you actually count the number of messages in the response, and calculate the offset accordingly, because responses sometimes have less items.